# Squid3 for Debian updates with upstream proxy

Tags: debian, proxy, squid, apt

I often need to setup new Debian servers, so I'm trying to setup a Squid proxy to cache apt-get updates/upgrades. But I always have a problem with some specific files it can retrieve.

Details:

- i'm behing a proxy which is the only way to get access to internet. I don't know what software is used.
- working on a ESX 5 : both squid server and clients
- tried with squeeze and wheezy Debian release, booting on netinst CD or on network (PXE), with preseed configuration file or not
- my Squid configuration looks like (parts of it)

  ```
  cache_peer      upstream_proxy.internal.domain.tld  parent  8080    0       no-query no-digest default
  cache_replacement_policy        heap LFUDA
  cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 1000 16 256
  maximum_object_size     200 MB
  refresh_pattern .              0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
  ```

When running Debian installation, at first it works well (squid delivers packages correctly) but at one moment it tries to retrieve **Packages.gz** file and this one never gets delivered. 
I see the following entries in access.log (not sure if they always appears or not, seems not)

```
1370855387.060 950995 <internal IP> TCP_MISS/200 679695 GET http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz - DEFAULT_PARENT/upstream_proxy.internal.domain.tld application/x-gzip
1370855542.916 947999 <internal IP> TCP_MISS/200 2247441 GET http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz - DEFAULT_PARENT/upstream_proxy.internal.domain.tld application/x-gzip
```

If I use my upstream proxy directly in my Debian installer all works fine, so it must be a configuration problem but I can't figure what.

Anyone has an idea of what can be the problem or how I can debug it?

Comment: why aren't you using the "right tool for the job" and running [apt-cacher-ng](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-cacher-ng) instead?

Comment: everytime i tried apt-cacher-ng or other apt dedicated tools i got problems too.

Comment: which kind of problems exactly?

Comment: can't remember exactly now, but apt-get update/upgrade fails on clients

Comment: I'm finally back to test apt-cacher-ng. At first it seems to work well. I hope version change between squeeze and wheezy (from 0.5 to 0.7) made a lot of improvements in the software and solved lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Your log entries are showing that the file is retrieved after a relatively long period of time (951 seconds / 947 seconds) but has differing length (679695 vs. 2247441 bytes) despite of the identical URI, which would indicate a problem. The transfer might be timing out after ~950 seconds and aborting - possibly forced by the upstream proxy.

Check if you can retrieve the file successfully in sane time when *not* using Squid:

```
export http_proxy="http://upstream_proxy.internal.domain.tld:8080"
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

and work from there isolating the issue. A `tcpdump` of the transfer between your Squid proxy instance and the remote proxy might help unclouding matters. Also, if available, check with the administrators / the technical support staff for the proxy you are using for possible causes for issues.

Comment: Retrieving this file directly via the upstream proxy works well, using wget, firefox or even the debian installer. Could it be a timeout problem on squid?

Comment: @daks the Squid "read timeout" is 15 minutes by default, which would somewhat fit into the picture. When the timeout expires, it should be logged according to the docs - check Squid's cache.log if you can find anything about that. Also, the question *why* it would time out (i.e. why the upstream proxy is not delivering any data after the initial couple of Kilobytes) would be unanswered yet.